# ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED error in Chrome when running MVC project and not in debug mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 application on a windows 8 machine with VS Express 2013.  It is not deployed to IIS at this time but is just a project.

All is well when I hit F5 and run it... the project loads and I can navigate around with no issues. I have Chrome set as my default browser for running the MVC application

My question is around what happens if I stop the debugging process in VS Express.  When I do that the MVC app, already loaded in Chrome, stops working i.e. meaning if try to navigate/reload any page I immediately receive the "Error 138 (net::ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED): Unable to access the network." in chrome.

Obviously, I can work around this be restarting the MVC application via F5 in Visual Studio again, but I find it annoying and many tutorials I've watched(Plural Sight for instance) I do not see them running into this issue.

Anybody clue me in on what's going on here and if I can fix it?

Comment: Are you debugging with IIS Express or the VS web server?

Comment: Essentially when you stop running/debugging the process is being killed. So when you try to access another page, there is no one (server) to handle the request. I have the same problem in VS 2013. No idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

When you press F5 you load your application to IIS Express server and you can use it, when you stop VS debugging process you are also killing that IIS.

What you need to do is deploying that application to IIS, so you can browse your application as long as IIS service is runing.

You can refer this article to deploy your application to your local IIS

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)